# How do I update a line in a file using Perl?

Tags: perl

I need update specific line in file.

I use regular expression. Finally, I run over next line.
The file `dog2cat` contains:

```
This example
The dog is drinking.
It is drinking milk.
```

My code:

```
open(FILE,"+<dog2cat");
while(<FILE>)
{
  my $line=$_;
  if($line =~ /dog/)
  {
    $line =~ s/dog/cat/;
    print FILE $line; 
  }
}
close FILE;
```

Finally the file contain

```
This example
The dog is drinking.
The cat is drinking.
```

I want to get

```
This example
The cat is drinking.
It is drinking milk.
```

Answer (score 2):

For simple file update tasks, you can use a Perl "one-liner":

```
perl -i -pe 's/dog/cat/g' dogcat.txt
```

The `-i` says to update the file you're working on (you can add an extension to it if you want to write to a new file. For example, `-i.bak` will write to a file named `dogcat.txt.bak`).

The `-p` says iterate over each line, and print it out (with `-i`, print back to the file).

`-e` executes whatever is between the quotes on each line in the file.

Comment: I will run this script from perl file: file.pl. is it ok ?

Comment: I would not recommend that. Don't run perl within perl. Within a script, it isn't easy for a newcomer to Perl to read and write to the same file, so you need to open another file for writing while you read the original, and then copy the new file over the old one when done.

Answer (score 1):

Open a second file for output, print to that one. Or print to the screen instead of another file, and when you run your script pipe the output into a file.

Comment: Why I need anorher file ?